# Dropping internet over WiFi

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, lan, wan

For well over a month now I've been having frequent outages in my outgoing connection over WiFi. The actual WiFi signal is stable and strong, and I'm perfectly able to reach devices in my home network, but webpages don't load & cloud services can't connect.
My first thought was "crappy router", so I called my ISP's customer service and got a new one (same model, Ubee evw321b). The problem remains. Toggling the WiFi connection resets the outgoing connection proper, until the next occurrence. There's no difference between 2.4gHz & 5gHz. There's also no pattern that I'm able to observe, and I know too little to accurately interpret the logs.

I've ran Wireless Diagnostics a couple of times, but like I said, I can't interpret them. I can't think of anything that might have changed in my network, but I'm starting to suspect that I'm generating too much traffic with torrents, 2 CCTV cams, Time Machine backups and other wireless devices. But if that were true, wouldn't the LAN become unreachable as well?

I've uploaded the full Wireless Diagnostics report [here](https://maxsteenbergen-2.stackstorage.com/index.php/s/SybjyUxJ9SSpFg0), maybe one of you can make some sense out of it.

EDIT: I forgot to mention that the issue is not limited to just my main iMac, my MBA and phones have similar if not the same issues.

Comment: Likely your WAN is saturated because it is much slower than your LAN. The torrents can do that.

Comment: What is the connection like if you connect to the router via ethernet cord?

Comment: @RonMaupin I figured that as well, but the problem persists even without seeding/leeching torrents.

Comment: @wardr No problems there.

Comment: Well then the problem clearly doesn't have anything to do with the wifi signal because all the devices are having the issue. So it's some kind of setting in your router as it relates to your LAN. Are you able to flash to DD-WRT and make your life a LOT easier.

Comment: @wardr I can't flash anything as it's an ISP supplied router. It doesn't even have proper logfiles...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely as you suspect - torrents.  Its not related to the amount of bandwidth, rather the number of simultaneous requests.  I believe you will probably find that crappy/limited connection tracking in the ISP's router is at fault - ie it can't keep track of the number of simultanous connections so it can route them correctly due to NAT.

You could try cut down on the number of simultaneous torrent connections and/or get a different router which can track more simultanous connections.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'll try cutting back on the torrents, see if it does make a difference after all. Just wondering though, did you find a clue to this in the logs? If so, where?

Comment: No, I only skimmed the logs - the ones I could interpret did not speak to the issue (and indeed I doubt its a wireless issue - particularly as all your devices share the problem).  I've come across similar problems before a few times.